# How to limit jQuery searches to a certain area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, tags

Let's say I have the following.

```
<div class="foo">
<div>
some text
<div class="bar">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
<div>
some text
<div class="bar">
some text
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want return all the divs of class "foo" that have "some text" inside the div class "bar." So the second would be returned, but not the second. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("div.bar:contains('some text')").parents(".foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
$('.foo:has(.bar:not(:empty))')
```

Make sure there are no characters inside the .bar, even spaces or newlines.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk4FB/

Comment: What is the `some text` part?

Comment: This returns all .foo that has a descendent .bar that is not empty.  So if 'some text' is in bar, it will return its parent foo.